# Redirect from page to dojo view

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

How can I redirect from a page html in worklight to DOJO views by clicking on simple button ?

Comment: See this Dojo-Worklight related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135007/how-do-i-use-dojo-inside-of-worklight-correctly

Answer (score 1):

If the Dojo view that you want to show is defined in the same HTML page, you can just get a reference to the View widget and call its show() function, so something like this:

```
require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry){
    registry.byId("myDojoView").show();
});
```